# Postman request with # character is not responding the proper output

Tags: url, get, request, character, postman

I am trying to get on specific object of my model which has "#" in its name ex:obj#1 like this, but when I use this object to retrieve its related attribute I am getting error like below:
 "error-message": "Request could not be completed because the relevant data model content does not exist"

can you please suggest me any way to request my object in postman?

Comment: it would be helpful to update your question with complete error, request, etc.

Comment: Might be worth taking a look through this before editing your question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Do you use "#" in the URL? It is a reserved character and needs to be encoded.
Here you can see the reserved URL characters and how to encode them:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding